# Returning & downcasting implementation objects in Java safely

Tags: java, casting

What's the Java equivalent of `class Something;` declarations at the top of header files? Or how does one safely expose references to internal implementation objects without them?

Example:

let's say I'm writing a UI for an image processing library. I have

```
interface ImageProcessor {
   public int countBirdsOnImage(Image image);
}
```

along with an internal implementation of the Image class (byte buffers, etc). The UI has both the processor and a factory of Images injected in it:

```
class ImageFactory {
  ImageInterface loadImage(File file);
}
```

so in theory one could write

```
class UIWindow {
   private ImageInterface lastImage;
   private ImageFactory factory; // injected
   private ImageProcessor imageProcessor; // also injected

   public void onLoadButtonClicked() {
     lastImage = factory.loadImage("some.jpg");
   }

   public void onCountBirdsButtonClicked() {
     showToUser(imageProcessor.countBirdsOnImage(lastImage));
   }
}
```

However, both the UI and the processing library is large (1000s of classes), so I don't want any of them depend on the other, only interfaces. As in: I put some interfaces (... presumably something about an Image and the ImageProcessor) into `api.jar`, then `ui.jar` and `processor.jar` depend on the API; the UI eventually gets references to the actual implementation classes in `injector.jar` which depends on both (... but is small and doesn't take long to compile).

This is easy to accomplish in C/C++: the image library has a header file which has method declarations for e.g. `countBirdsOnImage(Image* image)`; the UI only passes the `Image *` pointers around so it never has to know what methods it has and how much storage it needs. (In fact, we don't even need explicit dependency injection as the linker does that for us.)

Meanwhile, in Java:

We can of course make `ImageInterface` not expose internal details about Image and include it in our API. Likewise, `countBirdsOnImage()` would take an `ImageInterface` and do the right thing. Except we'd need an ugly and unsafe cast from `ImageInterface` to `Image` since we can't assume we're getting back an actual `Image` instance. However, we have no way of referencing `Image` on the processor interface since that'd pull in all its fields and basically the entire image processor library as a dependency (what is the very thing we'd like to avoid).

What is the idiomatic way of solving this problem in Java? How does one return an "opaque" reference to other modules and is still be able to cast it back to its internal representation when someone calls in, passing only the interface?

Comment: Why do you have to assume you're getting an `Image` instance?

Comment: since, technically, someone else could subclass ImageInterface and pass it in; nothing would work though.